# Python serial data decode

Tags: python, pyserial

I read the serial data by the following python program.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout=0)

var = '\x11\x02\x01\x00\xEC'
ser.write(var)
time.sleep(1)
while True:
try:
   Data_in = ser.readline().encode('hex')
   DF1 = Data_in [6:8]
   DF2 = Data_in [8:10]
   CO2 = int(DF1, 16)*256 + int(DF2, 16)
   print "=========================="
      print "Found Packet: " + Data_in
      print "DF 1: " + DF1 + " DF2: " + DF2 + " | CO2 : " + CO2
      time.sleep(1)
   except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
      print('Data could not be read')
```

The output is returned successfully except CO2:

- Data_in : 160b01072f000601bb02fb0041a8
- DF1: 07
- DF2: 2f

If I would like to calculate the data by the below formula , the python program returns an error.

> CO2 = int(DF1, 16)*256 + int(DF2, 16)

**Error**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\workspace\aqi\testserialv1.py", line 40, in 
    except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'SerialTimeoutException'

Comment: Please post the error's stacktrace

Comment: nothing from what you have shown should cause an error

Comment: By default, CO2 will print in decimal - 1839. Try printing hex(CO2) which will show 0x72f (the leading 0 of the 07 is suppressed).

Comment: Use `except serial.SerialTimeoutException`, not `except ser.SerialTimeoutException`.

Comment: `SerialTimeoutException` is only raised on timed out writes, not reads.

Comment: `try:` some tried `except Exception,e: print e`

Comment: Does the code you posted *actually work* _as posted_? (BTW I don't believe you because there must be a try: line before the except line) Which is line 40? Looks like the error is nothing to do with decoding the data because df12 and df2 print values correctly...

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed the try line during the code posting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comment given by CivFan. After I modify the code to

```
 serial.SerialTimeoutException
```

it works fine. Here is the complete code

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout=0)
var = '\x11\x02\x01\x00\xEC'

while True:
  try:
    ser.write(var)
    time.sleep(1)
    Data_in = ser.readline().encode('hex')
    print "=========================="
    print "Found Packet: " + Data_in

    Data_length = int( Data_in [2:4], 16)
    if Data_length == 11:
        DF1 = int( Data_in [6:8], 16)
        DF2 = int( Data_in [8:10], 16)
        CO2 = DF1*256.0 + DF2

        DF3 = int( Data_in [10:12], 16)
        DF4 = int( Data_in [12:14], 16)
        VOC = (DF3* 256 + DF4) / 100.0

        DF5 = int( Data_in [14:16], 16 )
        DF6 = int( Data_in [16:18], 16 )
        RH = (DF5*256.0 + DF6) / 10.0

        DF7 = int( Data_in [18:20], 16)
        DF8 = int( Data_in [20:22], 16)
        Temp = (DF7*256.0 + DF8-500) / 10.0

        DF9 = int( Data_in [22:24], 16)
        DF10 = int( Data_in [24:26], 16)
        PM25 = DF9*256.0 + DF10

        print "CO2 : " + str(CO2) + " VOC : " + str(VOC) + " RH : " + str(RH) + " Temp : " + str(Temp) + " PM : " + str(PM25)
        time.sleep(5)
except serial.SerialTimeoutException:
    print('Data could not be read')
```